# Trac - Windows - How's trac projects organized?

Tags: svn, bug-tracking, trac

I'm following official guide to install Trac on windows xp. Now all were installed, and i am told to do

```
trac-admin c:\trac initenv
```

As i have multiple SVN repositories organized like

```
../SVN/Repository/project 1
../SVN/Repository/project 2
../SVN/Repository/project 3
```

My question is if the folder 'trac' will be a root folder that holds all my projects, in this case, i would name the folder 'projects'. But if it is not the root, i think i should name it by the project name say 'project 1' ?

And if the latter is right, does it mean i should run several times "trac-admin c:\projectname initenv" for my projects ?

Comment: Are you sure you are following the official guide? The initenv command in the official guide I can find says different: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnWindowsStandalone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `trac-admin <..> initenv` creates a new instance of trac. If you want separate instances of trac for each of your projects, then creating separate trac environments is what you should do.

If you want to use a single instance of trac for all your projects located in a single svn repository, then you should create a single environment for trac. Never tried running a single instance of trac with several repositories, don't know if it is possible. You might have to move all the projects to a single repo.

At work we have several loosely related projects each with their own repository and an instance of trac running on windows and we have everything organized roughly like this:

```
- projects
  - project_1
    - trac - trac environment for project 1
    - svn - svn repository for the project
    - misc - auth data and other stuff
  - project_2
    - trac - trac environment for project 2
    - svn - svn repository for the project 2
    - misc - auth data and other stuff
<..>
```

Comment: looks good, but i use visualsvn server which seems don't allow specify location for each repo. i did some test, now know more about trac, how to organize data folders is actually under user's control

Comment: It's not (yet) possible to run one trac instance with multiple SVN repos.  They are however working on it.